# BottomSheet with ViewPager and Fragments?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, androiddesignsupport, bottom-sheet

I want a view that just like in older version of StreetView.

[image: refer this]

I have tried BottomSheetBehavior with ViewPager, but dynamic height of its fragments not working properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an CustomViewPager we can set height of fragment

```
public class CustomPager extends ViewPager {

private View mCurrentView;

public CustomPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

@Override
public void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (mCurrentView == null) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        return;
    }
    int height = 0;
    mCurrentView.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
    int h = mCurrentView.getMeasuredHeight();
    if (h > height) height = h;
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);

    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}

public void measureCurrentView(View currentView) {
    mCurrentView = currentView;
    requestLayout();
}

public int measureFragment(View view) {
    if (view == null)
        return 0;

    view.measure(0, 0);
    return view.getMeasuredHeight();
}}
```

and add in adapter add these lines too

```
private int mCurrentPosition = -1;

    @Override
    public void setPrimaryItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.setPrimaryItem(container, position, object);
        if (position != mCurrentPosition) {
            Fragment fragment = (Fragment) object;
            CustomPager pager = (CustomPager) container;
            if (fragment != null && fragment.getView() != null) {
                mCurrentPosition = position;
                pager.measureCurrentView(fragment.getView());
            }
        }
    }
```